# Tree Tables Select Command

Tags: sql, select, tree

I have 5 tables in my DB

Brands ---> Category ---> Type ---> TSeries ---> Parts

How can I select the brand name from [Brands] table where the PartID = " 1 "

[Category] has brandID , [Type] has CategoryID , [TSeries] has TypeID , and [Parts] has SeriesID

Answer (score 1):

<strike>How can i</strike> **select** <strike>the</strike> **[brand name] from Brands** <strike>table</strike> **where** <strike>the</strike> **PartID = ' something '**

Comment: Something mean = 1 or 2 or 3 any ID .. the most important that the brandID not exist on Parts Table

Comment: You need to edit your question to include these details, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
select brandname from Brands
inner join Category on Brands.ID=Category.BrandID
inner join  Type on Category.ID=Types.CategoryID 
inner join ..... 
where PartsID='sth'
```

Consider, re-Designing your Database, cause this database structure makes  big querying issues..

Comment: BrandID not exist in Parts Table .. In Parts Table Have SeriesID and TSeries table have TypeID and .... etc

Comment: which is the secondary key between Brands and Parts table?

Comment: [Category] have brandID , [Type] have CategoryID , [TSeries] have TypeID , [Parts] have SeriesID

Comment: thank you :) thats it :)

SELECT        Brands.BrandName
FROM            Brands INNER JOIN
                         Category ON Brands.BrandID = Category.BrandID INNER JOIN
                         Type ON Category.CategoryID = Type.CategoryID INNER JOIN
                         TSeries ON Type.TypeID = TSeries.TypeID INNER JOIN
                         Parts ON TSeries.SeriesID = Parts.SeriesID
WHERE        (Parts.PartID = '2')